# How do i set values back into a map in jquery?

Tags: jquery, dictionary

This is the code that of my jsp page which displays a window with columns.Each column corresponds to a form

```
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/include/pagedirectives.jsp"%>

<div style="background: #D6E8FF; padding: 10px;" class="advanced_search">
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/include/page.topmessagebox.jsp"%>

<table class="form" cellspacing="0" id="requestSubmissionEform">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="label"><b>Label</b></td>
            <c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="5" step="1" varStatus ="status">
            <th id="form_${i}"  class="label" align="left"><b>Form ${(pageNumber * 5) + i}</b></th>
            </c:forEach>
        </tr>

        <c:forEach items="${eformDetailsList}" var="eformDetails"
            varStatus="status">

            <tr id="serviceTypeWithEform">
                <td class="label">
                    <label for="${eformDetails.id}_0"><c:out value="${eformDetails.label}" /></label>
                     <input type="hidden" id="label_${eformDetails.id}_0" value="${eformDetails.label}" name="label_0"></input>
                     <input type="hidden" id="index_${eformDetails.id}_0" value="${eformDetails.id}" name="index_0"></input>
                </td>
                <c:if test="${eformDetails.controlType==1}">
                    <td id="Col0" style="visibility: visible;">
                        <input id="eformDetail_${eformDetails.id}_0" class="eformDetail" type="text" value="" name="form_0"></input>
                    </td>
                    <td id="Col1" style="visibility: visible;">
                        <input id="eformDetail_${eformDetails.id}_1" class="eformDetail" type="text" value="" name="form_1"></input>
                    </td>
                    <td id="Col2" style="visibility: visible;">
                        <input id="eformDetail_${eformDetails.id}_2" class="eformDetail" type="text" value="" name="form_2"></input>
                    </td>
                    <td id="Col3" style="visibility: visible;">
                        <input id="eformDetail_${eformDetails.id}_3" class="eformDetail" type="text" value="" name="form_3"></input>
                    </td>
                    <td id="Col4" style="visibility: visible;">
                        <input id="eformDetail_${eformDetails.id}_4" class="eformDetail" type="text" value="" name="form_4"></input>
                    </td>
                </c:if>
            </tr>

        </c:forEach>
        <c:if test="${empty eformDetailsList}">
            <tr id="serviceTypeWithNoEform">
                <td><b>There is no eform associated with this Service Type</b></td>
            </tr>
        </c:if>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the jquery used to obtain the values from the jsp page :

```
var labels0=$('input[name="label_0"]').map(function(){
    return $(this).val() }).get();  
var index0=$('input[name="index_0"]').map(function(){
    return $(this).val() }).get();  
var fields0 = $('input[name="form_0"]').map(function(){
    return $(this).val() }).get();
var fields1 = $('input[name="form_1"]').map(function(){
    return $(this).val() }).get();
var fields2 = $('input[name="form_2"]').map(function(){
    return $(this).val() }).get();
var fields3 = $('input[name="form_3"]').map(function(){
    return $(this).val() }).get();
var fields4 = $('input[name="form_4"]').map(function(){
    return $(this).val() }).get();
```

On click of save,I have saved the values.When i open the form again i want the saved values to re-appear in my text boxes.Is there a way to re set the values back to the map?

Comment: You should do it server-side (jsp), populating values inside your foreach

Answer (score 0):

(I think you should do it with jsp..) 
Anyway, assuming you have the js array:

```
var label_0_values = ['value 1', 'value 2', ...];
```

With jQuery, you would populate like this:

```
$('input[name="label_0"]').each(function(i){
   $(this).val(label_0_values[i]);
});
```

And the same for your other inputs

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: It enters the loop but i am unable to set the values..Not sure why.I am trying this operation for form_0